# Break Down A Loop Based Solution In An Event

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have generated a set of reference numbers using nested loops and have displayed them in a combobox following a button click but now i want each one of these numbers to be displayed sequentially in a textbox on every button click. My ultimate motive is to generate a unique ID on each button click.

```
    char ch, sh;
    int i;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (sh = 'A'; sh <= 'Z'; sh++)
        {
            for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(i + ch.ToString()+sh.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? Just the line of code to display the same data in your textbox?

Comment: You want all the reference numbers written to a text box, or only the one selected in the combo box?

Comment: You want to: on btn click, move comboBox1.Items[0] to textBoxN. where n = number of items in comboBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first we can create an iterator block to generate a sequence of values based on your current definition:

```
//TODO: rename method to something meaningful
public static IEnumerable<string> GenerateStrings()
{
    for (char sh = 'A'; sh <= 'Z'; sh++)
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                yield return string.Concat(i, ch, sh);
}
```

Then we can create an instance of this sequence as an instance field and get the next item each time the button is clicked:

```
private IEnumerator<string> stringSequence = GenerateStrings().GetEnumerator();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (stringSequence.MoveNext())
        textbox.Text = stringSequence.Current;
}
```

On a side note, normally one would want to dispose of `IEnumerator<T>` objects when done with them.  While you certainly could dispose of this object within the form's `Dispose` method, in this particular case there isn't anything for the enumerator to clean up, so it's not necessary, just be wary since many enumerators *do* need to be disposed.